# wbgapi: resolve country name

Tags: python, function, api, iterator

I'd like to use the `wbgapi` to get a list of countries with GDP per capita for 2021, with "normal" country names.

```
import wbgapi as wb

gdppercap=wb.data.DataFrame('NY.GDP.PCAP.CD', wb.region.members('WLD'))

# how do I pass the coder function to the rename method here, so that it returns the "WBG NAME"? 
gdppercap['YR2021'].sort_values(ascending = False).rename(index = wb.economy.coder)
```

The coder function works like this:

```
wb.economy.coder(['ARG', 'Korea'])

ORIGINAL NAME   WBG NAME    ISO_CODE
ARG             Argentina   ARG
Korea           Korea, Rep. KOR
```

But I don't understand how to isolate the second column, which is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done through `wb.economy.coder_report`:

```
def country_code_to_human_name(country_code):
    # Example: [['ORIGINAL NAME', 'WBG NAME', 'ISO_CODE'], ['ARG', 'Argentina', 'ARG']]
    report = wb.economy.coder_report(wb.economy.coder([country_code]))
    # -1: First element contains column labels, last element contains the actual data
    # 1: Second element contains the human readable country name
    return report[-1][1]

gdppercap.rename(index=country_code_to_human_name, inplace=False)
```

Found through introspection:

```
class Coder(dict):
    '''Class returned by coder if passed a list of terms
    '''

    def __repr__(self):
        rows = self._coder_report()
        columns = rows.pop(0)
        return tabulate(rows, tablefmt='simple', headers=columns)
```

and

```
def coder_report(economies):

    global _coder_names

    rows = [('ORIGINAL NAME', 'WBG NAME', 'ISO_CODE')]
    for k,v in economies.items():
        if v:
            wb_name = _coder_names.get(v, '')
        else:
            wb_name = ''

        rows.append((k, wb_name, v))

    output = []
    for row in rows:
        output.append([row[0], row[1], row[2]])
    
    return output
```